# Curved corners in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I understand that Internet Explorer is poor at supporting CSS3 - but is there any way to create curved corners when using divs like you are able to do in FF and Safari in IE?

Can anyone provide working code examples I can use to learn how to code this correctly.

Thanks

Jamie.

Comment: Duplicate of [Implementing rounded corners with IE fallback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112854/implementing-rounded-corners-with-ie-fallback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ever Google is your friend:

Try: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

This zip file has working code examples for Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8:

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip

IE9 should I believe support css3 corner code natively.

Comment: Great Suggestion. That's what I was after - this gives me some code examples to play around with.

Answer (score 6):

CSS pie is a great option.

http://css3pie.com/

It's very simple to use - just drop in a htc file, enter your css3 styles, and add the following behaviour:

```
#someselector {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

It's generally a good idea to use a conditional stylesheet for <= IE 8 as well, and in that case you'd add the behaviour in only that stylesheet as it's obviously not needed for other browsers.

As an aside, use the shorthand (if necessary) instead of individual corner properties as this will cause issues. Example: border-radius: 8px; or border-radius: 8px 7px 4px 3px; (top right bottom left)

Comment: +1 Amazing link. There are also a number of references to similar/related projects in the PIE documentation. It's a shame it can't fix the *rest* of IE6/7 :-)